# Como usar uma variável como parte de um comando?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como eu posso usar o valor de uma variável como parte de um comando?

Exemplo

```
count = 1
tn.write(b'ip address 10.0.0.count 0\n')
```

Eu gostaria que o valor 1 da variável `count` fosse o último dígito do endereço de IP no comando.

Comment: Helder, traduz sua pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Seja bem vindo SO em português. Aqui nós falamos em pt-br, por favor, traduza sua pergunta e não se esqueça de fazer o [tour] para compreender como a comunidade funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Helder, acredito que esteja querendo substituir o valor presente na variável count na string, existem diversas formas de fazer isso no Python, abaixo alguns exemplos:

```
count = 1

print(f'ip address 10.0.0.{count} 0\n')
print('ip address 10.0.0.' + str(count) + ' 0\n')
print('ip address 10.0.0.%s 0\n'%count)
print('ip address 10.0.0.{} 0\n'.format(count))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou testar agora...

Comment: E peço desculpas por postar em ingles...

Comment: eu tentie a seguinte solução: ` tn.write(b'ip address 10.0.0.%s 0\n'%count)`  porém ele da erro, diz que **TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'int'** , mas não entendo afinal tenho o **b** fazendo encode para bytes..